# Fargate ThrottlingException Rate exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am attempting to run 30 Fargate tasks at once and I am receiving "ThrottlingException: Rate exceeded".

In the [ECS Service Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_limits.html), it mentions that the default limit for concurrent Fargate tasks is 50.

Am I being throttled for something other than the number of concurrent Fargate tasks? For example, is Fargate registering a container instance for each task; and thus I'm exceeding the container instance registration rate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I reached out to AWS support and got the following answer:

> ECS' run-task API, when launching a Fargate task, is throttled at 1 TPS
>   by default with a burst rate of 10. This means that you can--at
>   most--launch 10 tasks every 10 seconds. As such, we recommend that
>   [you] use some backoff strategy on [your] end when launching tasks.
>   Alternatively, [you] can use ECS create-service, in which case ECS will
>   ensure that all tasks are run in time while honoring the throttle
>   rate.

Essentially, although I could run 30 tasks concurrently, I couldn't start all 30 tasks at the same time due to the throttling of the run-task API for Fargate tasks.

As of November 7th 2018, this limit is not mentioned in the AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_limits.html